# Problemas com shortcodes aninhadas

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá! Estou tentando utilizar algumas shortcodes aninhadas, porém não estou tendo êxito.

As shortcodes são estas, em ordem de declaração na functions.php:

```
function p_generico_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    return '<p class="pov generico">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'pov-generico', 'p_generico_shortcode' );
```

Segunda:

```
function f_moca_shortcode( $atts , $content = null )
{
    return '<p class="fala moca">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'fala-moca', 'f_moca_shortcode' );
```

Ao tentar utilizar:

```
[fala-moca]TEXT[pov-generico]OTHER TEXT[/pov-generico][/fala-moca]
```

estou obtendo:

```
<p class="fala moca">TEXT</p>
<p class="pov generico">OTHER TEXT</p>
```

Em vez de:

```
<p class="fala moca">TEXT<p class="pov generico">OTHER TEXT</p></p>
```

Percebi que, ao aninhar shortcodes que retornam HTML com elementos diferentes (ex. p e span) ele processa corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVIDO!
O problema simplesmente era pelo fato do wordpress [não aceitar (assim como os padrões w3c), duas tags p aninhadas](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185765/71362). Alterando para span a tag filha resolveu tudo.